# Split Multi-Module maven project into separate WAR files

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-3

I have a maven project which contains several sub-module projects. Currently when I build the project, one WAR file is generated.

Is it possible to specify through the POM that seperate WAR files should be built for each module in the project, so I can host the war files on separate servers if need be?

Cheers.

Comment: Can you explain us in a better way your problem, maybe you could add your Pom files, and the types of application server that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the packaging in the sub modules `war`:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

... and make the packaging for the parent project `pom`:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```